# undefined reference to 'winMain' in Cygwin terminal

Tags: winmain, cygwin-64

$ gcc -Wl,--export-all-symbols
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/../../../../lib/libcygwin.a(libcmain.o): in function `main': /usr/src/debug/cygwin-3.5.0-1/winsup/cygwin/lib/libcmain.c:37:(.text.startup+0x7b): undefined reference to` WinMain'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

actually first I got -rdynamic related error so I have replaced it by gcc -Wl,--export-all-symbols then i got above errors
Any help?
Windows version -11
cygwin version-11.4.0